# Cannot remove docker build cache

Tags: docker

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to run
`docker build .`

But it loads from cache and fails.(docker for windows)

Things I tried :

- docker build --no-cache .
- removing docker completely
- factory reset from docker gui
- docker system prune -a
- docker builder prune

[image]

And still build command tried to load from cache and fails!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) , in this case your second image contains HALF of the error, only the first half. What is the second, or what is the COMPLETE, error message ? (Please post it as TEXT)

Comment: It will also help to [edit] the question to include a [mcve].  What's in the Dockerfile; why don't you expect its results to be cached?